# What is service or entity broadcasts transactions with OP_RETURN data starting with "LP..."?

Tags: transactions, op-return

There have been quite a few `OP_RETURN` transactions recently where OP_RETURN data in the scriptPubKey starts with `4c 50` which is `LP` as ASCII.

For example these transactions:
 - `ccce20a2b4c79d80fe57bd4008c398c548cefc7f353e71044353432f434d8e6a`
 - `2d02e75f6f72a1e633e4f1b36066428f1904ca5859bc6a711806961b8b6fbfd3`
 - `f85a0efd449f193605048b73dd7bb0287c7a331ab92755497b4d77806090849e`
 - `b193bb721f21e2efc9dcfd9bb8ab8753f9a70f6ff7ce8bbffb0a173a45adf6b0`
 - ... and a lot more (6447 in the last two hours at the time of writing this)

Since the first bytes are usually used as an identifier (e.g. `omni` for OmniLayer) I'd be curious if anybody happens to know where this could originate from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting bytes `4c 50` has nothing to do with ASCII encoding. `0x4c` represents opcode `OP_PUSHDATA1` which indicates that the next opcode bytes is data to be pushed onto the stack. So in the examples that you have given, `4c 50` will indicate pushing the next 0x50 bytes onto the stack which is 80 bytes in decimal. The question you should have been asking is why the data that has been encoded on the stack for all the transactions that you have listed starts with `00 06 4e`